# Angular 5 How to Call Http Get a Second Time

Tags: angular, rxjs

I am developing an Angular 5 application (RXJS 5). I have a service to provide calls to my API. Here is my function to get an array of ExclusionTypes:

```
getExclusionTypes(): Observable<IExclusionType[]> {
  return this.http.get<IExclusionType[]>('api/exclusionTypes');
}
```

When my application first loads (`appComponent.onInit`) it subscribes to `getExclusionTypes` and on receiving the data calls a service to update a BehaviourSubject with the data as follows:

```
this.exclusionTypeSubscription = this.exclusionTypeApiService.getExclusionTypes().subscribe(exclusionTypes => {
  if (exclusionTypes != null) {

    // Set the exclusionTypes behaviourSubject in the exclusionService
    this.exclusionService.setExclusionTypes(exclusionTypes);
  }
});
```

This ensures that all components subscribing to the local BehaviourSubject receive the data.

The SQL data can be edited by other external applications so I have an 'Update' button with the intention of requesting an Http GET against the API and on receiving the data, update the local BehaviourSubject. Clicking Update calls the following function in the Update Button's component:

```
updateLocalData() {

  this.exclusionTypeSubscription = this.exclusionTypeApiService.getExclusionTypes().subscribe(exclusionTypes => {
    if (exclusionTypes != null) {
      this.exclusionService.setExclusionTypes(exclusionTypes);
    }
  });

}
```

`exclusionService.setExclusionTypes` is as follows:

```
public setExclusionTypes(exclusionTypes: IExclusionType[]) {
  this._exclusionTypes.next(exclusionTypes);
}
```

However when `updateLocalData()` gets called no data is received! I just cannot figure out why I cannot subscribe to the `getExclusionTypes` observable for a second time? Any advise very welcome.

Comment: It seems legit, can you check if the subscribe in the updateLocalData() is fired and what it returns?

Comment: Can you also show `setExclusionTypes()` implementation?

Comment: `updateLocalData()` is being fired. How would I find out what is being returned?

Comment: I have edited my post to include `setExclusionTypes()`.

Comment: I also have checked that the web API controller is receiving the GET request and returning the data when `updateLocalData` is called, which it is.

Comment: Can you check that `this.exclusionService.setExclusionTypes(exclusionTypes);` in `updateLocalData()` method is actually executed? Are you sure you are not completing the `_exclusionTypes` BehavoiurSubject or unsubscribe from it in the components which should receive the updates?

Comment: `this.exclusionService.setExclusionTypes(exclusionTypes);` is not being called. What I have found is this: I created a `exclusionTypeSubscription ` object so that I can `unsubscribe()` from it during `onDestroy()`. As above, this is used like `this.exclusionTypeSubscription = this.exclusionTypeApiService.getExclusionTypes().subscribe(...);`. This is not working. However if I simply call `this.exclusionTypeApiService.getExclusionTypes().subscribe(...);` I get the data returned in the `onNext` event.

Comment: Hands up, schoolboy error! After calling `updateLocalData()` I called `this.router.navigate(['/home']);` navigating the user back to the 'Home' page after updating the data. This of course called `onDestroy()` which unsubscribed from my API service, hence no data returned! This explains why, when I called `this.exclusionTypeApiService.getExclusionTypes().subscribe(...);` it worked because I had not set `this.exclusionTypeSubscription` so it didn't unsubscribe. Thank you all for your help though.